# I get a Solid black page when printing some pdf files

Tags: printing, hp, pdf

I know that there was already another person who has made the same question, but until today I didn't find a solution. When I print some pdf files I get a hole black page made of black lines. I usually convert the pages to png in order to print them, but sometimes this doesn't solve the problem. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and my printer is a HP Laserjet M1212nf MFP. I have already reinstalled the drivers twice, but the problem remains.When I convert the pages to png, the transparencies are sometimes printed as black. I should be very grateful if someone can solve this problem. (PS: I'm sorry for my English)

Regards,